# Pandas: Using .loc to find items, iterate a list within the column cells

Tags: python, pandas

I want add a value of `True` to column `sku_match`, if column `ids` contains a value matching `sku`.

My `ids` column contains lists, like `['123', '567-A', 'BH2228']`

My current code is only working if the matching value is in position `[0]` of the list (obviously):

```
sku = '567-A'
df.loc[df.ids.str[0] == sku, 'sku_match'] = True
```

I would like to check against *all* the items in the list. In non-pandas-like pseudocode it would be like

```
sku = '567-A'
for index, row in .df:
   if sku in df[index].ids:
       df[index].sku_match = True
```

I've tried a bunch of various list comprehensions with `.loc` which I'm pretty sure is the wrong approach, I've tried `isin()` but it seems to do the opposite of what i want to do, and none of the other stackoverflow questions address this specific situation as far as i can tell.  Can I iterate each row's lists in this context, within the `.loc`? Or do i need to take another approach to this problem entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expand the Series to be 2-dimensional, then check that any value of each record equals the sku:

```
>>> ids = [['123', '567-A', 'BH2228'],
...        ['567-A', 'xxx', 'BH2229'],
...        ['zzz', '679-B', 'BH2220']]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ids': ids})
>>> sku = '567-A'

>>> df['sku_match'] = df['ids'].apply(pd.Series).eq(sku).any(axis=1)
>>> df
                   ids  sku_match
0  [123, 567-A, BH2...       True
1  [567-A, xxx, BH2...       True
2  [zzz, 679-B, BH2...      False
```

If you're concerned with runtime speed, you could also convert the column to a list and operate on that:

```
>>> df['sku_match'] = tuple(map(lambda x: sku in x, df.ids.tolist()))
```

Comment: Good approach but is little bit slow .

Comment: Yes, was just timing the second approach as you posted your answer @Wen.  It's not even close

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple list computation with `in`

```
['567-A' in x for x in df.ids.values]
Out[852]: [True, True, False]
```